# Cordova 3.3.1 not scaffolding projects

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I've just upgraded cordova to the 3.3.1 version via npm, the problem is that when I create a new project, the structure: js, index.html, etc. that previously was generated by the `create` command no longer gets generated.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some issues with cordova-cli after updating it via npm. Removing .cordova fodler in user home directory fixed some in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I copied my android folder to an external location (e.g. home dir) and then did `add platform android` to get the structuring of 3.3.1 (since they changed where things are).  Then I just merged the new version with the copy in the external location.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `cordova prepare <your platform>`

e.g.
`cordova prepare ios` or 
`cordova prepare android`

...at the root of your project.